# Migration from server 2k3 to 2k12r2

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012-r2, migration

I recentely joined as System administrator.
And I have to migrate server 2003 from 2012R2.
What precations should be taken for this?
And how to complete this process?
Please guide stepwise as I m d only sys admin here(little worried).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you supposed to upgrade the existing machine to Windows Server 2012 R2? Or supposed to port software over to a new machine with the new OS?

Comment: Not upgrade. Want to migrate from older one to new one with new SuperMicro Blade servers.

Comment: And... what are you intending to migrate over?

Comment: Wanted to migrate from Windows 2003 server to 2k12R2 as company wants.

Comment: I do not think you understand the scenario here - what exactly is _in_ the Windows 2003 server that has to be migrated over? What is it that the brand new Windows Server 2012 R2 is lacking that the Windows 2003 server has? Are you operating an Active Directory domain? Exchange Server? SQL Server?

Comment: Ohh..gotcha.All 5 FSMO roles are on 2k3. nothing else.
No exchange. No SQL.

Comment: @VinD So you want to upgrade your DC. How many DCs do you have now? What are the reasons for this upgrade? What's your current Forest\Domain level?
I think that in general the safest route would be to create a secondary DC, let the data replicate, take over the 5 roles, shutdown the old one and upgrade your Forest\Domain level.

Answer (score 3):

See, you were talking about Active Directory migration - suggest you edit your question to include more such details. Have a look at the following articles for some guidance.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/04/02/step-by-step-active-directory-migration-from-windows-server-2003-to-windows-server-2012.aspx

http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/57636-migrate-active-directory-from-server-2003-to-server-2012-r2

Comment: I have one doubt..I m not sure are we using or not SQL server and Exchange server in our enviroment on the same DC.
Is there any way to check out this?? What i need to check for this?

Comment: You can always look at the control panel Add/Remove Programs http://wistinga.sourceforge.net/safarp/shot-arp.png